# Let typescript know what type an object is

Tags: typescript, types

I am writing a library that allows user to specify a callback. Like this:

```
interface IParams {
  context: any;
  okCallback: (value: string) => void
  ... etc ...
}

class MsgBox {
   static getInput(params: IParams) {
      ....
      okCallback.call(params.context, value);
   }
}
```

The purpose of the context is to put the callback in a context. So for example I can do this:

```
MsgBox.getInput({
     context: this,
     okCallback(value) {
        this.accessToEnclosingClass
     }
}
```

Since the callback needs access to properties of the calling class. This makes it more convenient than using $.proxy() all over the place.

This works correctly, however, the problem is with the typescript compiler. Within the callback typescript does not know the type of `this`, and so treats it like any, and doesn't do any type checking for me, something which has lead to a lot of frustration.

Is there a way to let Typescript compiler know what the type of `this` is in this context? I can do:

```
     okCallback(value) {
        const self = this as EnclosingClassType;
        self.accessToEnclosingClass
     }
```

Which does work, but I'd rather use `this` (because otherwise there is an opportunity for accidentally using `this`, leading to possible non compile type type errors.

Of course this is a simple example, the challenge happens when okCallback is not defined in `this` context, but as a separate function.

Any suggestions or thoughts on this?

Comment: Typing of `this` is available in TS 2.0. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6739.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which saves the context of `this`:

```
MsgBox.getInput({
     context: this,
     okCallback: (value) => {
        this.accessToEnclosingClass
     }
}
```

The compiler (and IDE) will understand that as well and so won't treat `this` as any.

Comment: Arrow functions go beyond just type checking: you can no longer change the `this` context inside `okCallback` using `okCallback.call(aDifferentThis)`. This means that `getInput` can just do `okCallback(value)`, and you might as well replace `IParams` with just `(value:string)=>void` as the `context` field is never needed.